# Get instance variable of costum transformer in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline

I am tasked with a supervised learning problem on a dataset and want to create a full Pipeline from complete beginning to end.
Starting with the train-test splitting. I wrote a custom class to implement sklearns train_test_split into the sklearn pipeline. Its fit_transform returns the training set. Later i still want to accsess the test set, so i made it an instance variable in the custom transformer class like this:

```
self.test_set = test_set
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class train_test_splitter([...])
[... 
...]
    def transform(self, X):
        train_set, test_set = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2)
        self.test_set = test_set
        return train_set

split_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('splitter', train_test_splitter() ),    
])
df_train = split_pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

Now i want to get the test set like this:

```
df_test = splitter.test_set
```

Its not working. How do I get the variables of the instance "splitter". Where does it get stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the steps of a pipeline in a number of ways.  For example,

```py
split_pipeline['splitter'].test_set
```

That said, I don't think this is a good approach.  When you fill out the pipeline with more steps, at `fit` time everything will work how you want, but when predicting/transforming on other data you will still be calling your `transform` method, which will generate a *new* train-test split, forgetting the old one, and sending the new *train* set down the pipe for the remaining steps.

Comment: Normally i would hard code the random seed with  random_state=42, so it always gets the same training-test sets. I want to put it into a Pipeline to try out different splitting methods (e.g. stratified sampling) and compare the cross-val error with the test error.

Comment: Setting a random state would fix the first italicized issue I pointed out, but not the second.